# How to add heroku key to git to work properly

Tags: git, heroku, github

I am using windows7. I have created heroku APP using

```
heroku create loka-xxxx
```

It will create an app for me with git link.

```
git@heroku.com:loka-xxxx.git
```

but when i do.

```
git push heroku master
```

It gives me this error
"Permission denied (publickey)".

Before heroku i had github installed on my window machine.
So, this is key error. For this when i do

```
heroku keys
```

this show me a key.

I want to know how add this heroku key to git and how to tell git to use different keys to use at different operations(default & heroku).

Comment: why you don't try with the github app? http://windows.github.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the steps i followed to make heroku work with git on my windows machine.
Step 1: create ssh rsa keys to use.
1.1 On windows to create ssh keys you need some additional tools [from here.](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Step 2: Generate ssh key using ***putty key-gen***. name this key as id_rsa. Now you have to pair of id_rsa key(pub&ppk).

Step 3:
Put these keys into your

```
c:\users\<user-name>\.ssh
```

folder.

Step 4.
Now go to the folder where your git is installed. like

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git
```

and try to create .ssh folder. Note: to create .ssh folder you need to run cmd as administrator and run mkdir .ssh.

Step 5.
Now put your id_rsa key pair in this folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh"

Step 6.
open your cmd again.
Goto your app folder and do initialize git again. here is the sequence of commands.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "This will be resolved now"
heroku keys:clear
heroku keys:add

git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:<your app>.git
```

Now you can do

`git push heroku master`. Hope i have covered all the steps for the windows user. for mac and unix user follow. 
[Winfield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21834062/1457016)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have your git keys, you can add your current SSH public key to Heroku to allow pushing with whatever key is already configured on your local git install:

```
> heroku keys:add
```

... and then select `id_rsa.pub` or whichever key you are using already.

This will allow you to push to github using your existing key.

If you have the private key for the public key already on your Heroku account (listed via `heroku keys`), you can over-write the default private key in `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` with your Heroku private key.

Comment: should be `$ heroku keys:add` ?

Comment: @Winfield i want to add heroku key to git. As i don't have id_rsa key with me. As you don't have the privilege to do ssh-keygen on windows cmd.

Comment: Added instructions for how to over-write default SSH private key

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assume you don't use windows as for windows it was bit different.