# Setting credentials to deploy to new account with Heroku using Win7

Tags: python, windows, heroku

I have a heroku account and have opened a second account with a different email.

When I try to deploy my project to the new account, I see:

```
$ heroku logout
Local credentials cleared.

(r2)
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: XXX@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Could not find an existing public key.
Would you like to generate one? [Yn] n
Authentication successful.

(r2)
$ git push heroku master

 !  Your account YYY@gmail.com does not have access to limitless-ocean-****.
 !
 !  SSH Key Fingerprint: 25:e2:80:******:05:dc

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
(r2)
```

How can I push my project to an app in the second account without conflicting with the first account?

Comment: in the .git folder check what it says in the config file for the heroku remote This folder may be hidden.
Also: Is limitless-ocean-**** an app from your old heroku account or one that you created in the new account?

Comment: limitless-ocean-****  is the new app

Answer (score 0):

On your heroku dashboard which account is listed as the owner under the Access tab? You may be able to transfer ownership of the app to your new account from the Settings tab, covered here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/transferring-apps

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm not interested in moving an existing app to the new account, I want to develop a new app within the new account.

Comment: The accepted answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789327/how-to-add-heroku-key-to-git-to-work-properly#